# Update a label on the IPhone when pressing a button on the Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit

I'm building an app that counts how many goals you have scored.

I would like to know what is the best way to send the data collected on the

Apple Watch to the IPhone ( and display it on the IPhone )

> Blockquote

```
// Watchkit extension 

     var count = 1


  // a label
     @IBOutlet weak var goals: WKInterfaceLabel!

  // a button in the Apple Watch
     @IBAction func addCount() {

         goals.setText("\(count++)")
    }

  // IPhone View Controller
     @IBOutlet weak var yourTeamScore: UILabel!
```

- I have already set my app groups for both the extension and the Apple Watch.
- Should I use NSUserDefaults to store the data on the extension and then send it to the IPhone App ( View Controller)?
- Is it possible to use openParentApplication:reply  to update the label on the IPhone  with data gathered on the Apple Watch

Answer (score 5):

This link might be helpful for you:

https://www.netfunctional.com/2015/04/watchkit-apps-sending-data-from-apple-watch-to-iphone/

Basically, you should call this method from the watchkitextension when you click the button:

```
 [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:yourDictionary reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        ....
    }];
```

And the iPhone app will call:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
   //Code to update the label
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Javier's answer, you could also try using Darwin Notifications. There's a fantastic project on GitHub called MMWormhole that wraps these notifications and makes it easy to pass data back-and-forth from your WatchKit app and the iPhone: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole